# Retrieve data from SQLite in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, xml

having problem in showing data in fragment from SQLite via recyclerView. When i click showfragment button it crash and show "Unfortunately App stoped".It has 6 java class and 4 xml
I'm giving my code below

## DbHelperAdapter.java

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DbHelperAdapter{

DbHelper helper;
public DbHelperAdapter(Context context){
    helper=new DbHelper(context);
}

public long insetData(String name,String password){
    SQLiteDatabase db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(DbHelper.NAME,name);
    contentValues.put(DbHelper.PASSWORD,password);
    long id=db.insert(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    db.close();
    return id;
}
public String getAllData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db= helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns={DbHelper.UID,DbHelper.NAME,DbHelper.PASSWORD};
    Cursor cursor=db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        int cid=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.UID));
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.NAME));
        String pass = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.PASSWORD));
        buffer.append(cid+" "+name+" "+pass+"\n");

    }
    return buffer.toString();
}

public List<Information> getAllData_a(){
    SQLiteDatabase db= helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns={DbHelper.UID,DbHelper.NAME,DbHelper.PASSWORD};
    Cursor cursor=db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    List<Information> data=new ArrayList<>();

    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        int cid=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.UID));
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.NAME));
        String pass = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.PASSWORD));
        Information current = new Information();
        current.u_id=cid;
        current.user=name;
        current.pass=pass;
        data.add(current);
    }
    return data;

}

public String getData(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db= helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns={DbHelper.NAME,DbHelper.PASSWORD};
    Cursor cursor=db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, DbHelper.NAME+" = '"+name+"' ", null, null, null, null);
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        String PersonName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.NAME));
        String pass = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.PASSWORD));
        buffer.append(PersonName+" "+pass+"\n");
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}

static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "demo";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "tbl_demo";
    private static final int VERSION_NAME=3;
    private static final String UID="_id";
    private static final String NAME="name";
    private static final String PASSWORD="Password";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+NAME+" VARCHAR(255),"+PASSWORD+" VARCHAR(255));";
    private static final String DROP_TABLE="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME+"";
    private Context context;

    public DbHelper(Context context){
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,VERSION_NAME);
        this.context=context;
        Message.message(context, "constructorCalled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            Message.message(context, "onCreateCalled");
        }catch (android.database.SQLException e){
            Message.message(context, ""+e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {
            Message.message(context, "onUpgradeCalled");
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        } catch (android.database.SQLException e) {
            Message.message(context, ""+e);
        }
    }
}
}
```

## Information.java

```
public class Information {
int u_id;
String user;
String pass;}
```

## MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

DbHelperAdapter dbHelperAdapter;
EditText userName;
EditText password;
EditText selectionName;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dbHelperAdapter = new DbHelperAdapter(this);

    userName= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    password= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    selectionName= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.selection_name);
}

public void addUser(View view){
    String user = userName.getText().toString();
    String pass = password.getText().toString();
    long id = dbHelperAdapter.insetData(user,pass);
    if(id<0){
        Message.message(this,"Unsuccessful");
    }
    else {
        Message.message(this,"Successfully insert A Row");
    }
}

public void getTheFragment(View view){
    Intent i= new Intent(this,MainActivity2.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

public void viewDetails(View view){
    String data=dbHelperAdapter.getAllData();
    Message.message(this,data);
}
public void getDataBySelection(View view){
    String name = selectionName.getText().toString();
    String selections=dbHelperAdapter.getData(name);
    Message.message(this,selections);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

## MainActivity2.java

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity2 extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        return new MyFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1;
    }
}}
```

## Myfragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
DbHelperAdapter dbHelperAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),dbHelperAdapter.getAllData_a());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    return layout;
}}
```

## RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<Information> data= Collections.emptyList();

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Information> data){
     inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
     this.data =data;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_raw,parent,false);
    MyViewHolder holder=new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Information current = data.get(position);
    holder.UID.setText(current.u_id);
    holder.USER.setText(current.user);
    holder.PASS.setText(current.pass);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView UID;
    TextView USER;
    TextView PASS;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        UID= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.u_id);
        USER = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user);
        PASS = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pass);
    }
}}
```

## activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:onClick="addUser"
    android:text="@string/add_user" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="viewDetails"
    android:text="View Details"
    android:id="@+id/view_details_btn"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/selection_name"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="GetSelectedData"
    android:onClick="getDataBySelection"
    android:id="@+id/getDataBySelection" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Show Fragment"
    android:onClick="getTheFragment"
    android:id="@+id/show_fragment"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

## activity_main_activity2.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

## custom_raw.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/u_id"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="UID"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/user"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="NAME"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pass"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="PASSWORD"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

## fagment_new.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

google drive link: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B0uBfXsWeMlgX0U5OE8tREhxQkk&usp=sharing

logcat errors:

```
02-02 22:15:27.455  10562-10562/com.maticoders.databasetest E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.maticoders.databasetest.MyFragment.onCreateView(MyFragment.java:29)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1411)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:698)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4919)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2200)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15635)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2165)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1443)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4872)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: so much information but no stacktrace :-(

Comment: I'd actually say TOO much information, this just asking SO at large to debug your code rather than asking a specific, answerable question. You'll need to compact this down to a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for it to be on-topic on this site.

Comment: Sorry Im new in stackoverflow 
here my some logcat errors:

02-02 22:15:27.455  10562-10562/com.maticoders.databasetest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.maticoders.databasetest.MyFragment.onCreateView(MyFragment.java:29)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786) #stefan

Comment: i just couldn't specify the problems thats why i give total code. Thanks for the suggestion @Aiken

Comment: It's also best to edit information into your question rather than posting it in comments when it's requested. You can do that by clicking the small 'edit' text beneath your question body.

Comment: thanks Aiken.  i solved it via errors of my logcat. I didn't pass the context and passed an integer value in a textView. now it's done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors were in my RecyclerViewAdapter Class
i didn't pass the context and passed an integer in textView
here is my RecylerViewAdapter Class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Information> data= Collections.emptyList();

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Information> data){
         this.context=context;
         inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
         this.data =data;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_raw,parent,false);
        MyViewHolder holder=new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Information current = data.get(position);
        holder.UID.setText(String.valueOf(current.u_id));
        holder.USER.setText(current.user);
        holder.PASS.setText(current.pass);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView UID;
        TextView USER;
        TextView PASS;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            UID= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.u_id);
            USER = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user);
            PASS = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pass);
        }
    }
}
```